# addNotificationBlock { RealmCollectionChange } crashes in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm using Realm for Swift and loading the data into a UITableView. There are roughly 200 data objects that are being gradually downloaded as I enter the screen, so there is a lot of insertion into the UITableView happening in my tests after the tableview has been displayed. I'm using the Realm example to addNotificationBlock with RealmCollectionChange as closely as I can and I'm getting two separate crashes that happen occasionally during this process.

1. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Can only add notification blocks from within runloops.'

This crash is occurring even though I make a point of pulling all the data from the main thread within my ViewController class.

2. *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1720
   **** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (27) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (17), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (9 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

This crash only started occurring after I replaced

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

with

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
          withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
          withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(modifications.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
          withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
```

in the .Update() section of my addNotificationBlock

Is there something I'm missing about Realm that is causing this? I suspect it's due to me not fully understand the inner mechanisms of this library.

Here's my code for reference:

```
self.exhibits = DataManager.getAllExhibitsSorted("id")
token = self.exhibits?.addNotificationBlock { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
  switch changes {
  case .Initial(_):

    self.exhibits = DataManager.getAllExhibitsSorted("id")
    self.exhibitListTableView.reloadData()
    break
  case .Update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):

    // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
    self.exhibitListTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.exhibitListTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(insertions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
      withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.exhibitListTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(deletions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
      withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.exhibitListTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(modifications.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) },
      withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.exhibitListTableView.endUpdates()

    break
  case .Error:
    NSLog("Error in notificationBlock")
    break
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be overcomplicating things a little here.

Realm `Results` objects are live and auto-updating. Meaning changes made to their underlying objects are updated automatically on the next iteration of the main run loop, so there's no need to perform a manual re-fetch on them. In your code there, you're re-assinging `self.exhibits` in the `.Initial` change notification, after the token has been generated, which may be causing some of your issues here. If you delete that line, it should just continue to work.

I'd recommend going through your code, and making sure that `self.exhibits` is only being assigned once, and that the change notification method is applied to just that one.

Let me know if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Ugh. That managed to fix it most of the time, but I'm still getting a NSInternalInconsistencyException when I turn wifi on and off during the download. It's probably a race condition between the notificationBlock.Update and the values that exist within self.exhibits. Even just some help on how to catch that error would probably be enough. None of the stuff in .Update is supposed to throw an error so I can't surround it with a do-catch.

Comment: For what it's worth I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you ever resolve this? It seems like a race condition somewhere inside Realm. I'm using the code 100% as shown in the Realm docs...